# Cannot remove text decoration underline

Tags: html, css

I cannot remove the `underline` from the following. I've tried setting `text-decoration: none` on all three classes as well.

```css
rs-friends-list-row {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
  font-size: 10px;
}
a .rs-friends-list-row {
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover .rs-friends-list-row {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">
  <div class="rs-friends-list-row">
    <div>
      <img class="rs-friends-user-image" src="assets/images/profileimg1.png" alt="img">
    </div>
    <div class="rs-friends-details"><span class="right-sidebar-friends-name">Lucile B. Nash</span>
      <br>Nanaimo</div>
    <div><span class="rs-friends-status online"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</a>
```

Comment: You have to apply `text-decoration:none;` directly to the `a` element

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`text-decoration` only applies to `a` and you are applying to child of `a` (the `div`), you need to apply to `a` (with class or not)

```css
.rs-friends-list-row {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
  font-size: 10px;
}
.some-class {
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover .rs-friends-list-row {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<a class="some-class" href="#">
  <div class="rs-friends-list-row">
    <div>
      <img class="rs-friends-user-image" src="assets/images/profileimg1.png" alt="img">
    </div>
    <div class="rs-friends-details"><span class="right-sidebar-friends-name">Lucile B. Nash</span>
      <br>Nanaimo</div>
    <div><span class="rs-friends-status online"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</a>
```

Comment: This contradicts the last question I had Dippas. We did not set a specific class for the link in my last question, which is why I was confused.

Comment: the class for the link is optional, just in the case you want to set `text-decoration:none` for this type of links, for examples, you want all links in website with `underline`, you set `a {text-decoration:underline}`, then you set this class `.not-underline{text-decoratione:none}` You really need to read CSS books/tutorials or articles

Comment: I'm still confused as to why the question I asked prior did not underline the text, yet in this scenario it does.

Comment: yes it does but it still doesn't explain why the last example we did behaves differently. I know that's not my question but I thought I did exactly the same thing with a different result.

Comment: @LiveWithPassion in my snippet it behaves like this...because i added `text-decoration:none` to `a`, you had `text-decoration:none` to `a .ch section` which was setting to section therefore not doing anything. and thats why you keep seeing the underline, this is really basic CSS, I strongly recommend a read about CSS either books or tutorials

Comment: Thanks for the help. It still does not explain why one scenario yields one result and an exact copy yields another. All good though. Cheers.

Comment: @LiveWithPassion did you re-visited my snippet in another answer?

Answer (score 1):

The link has the underline, so you should do

```
a {text-decoration: none;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are not targeting the anchor element itself when you put `a .re-friends-list-row`. When you do it that way you are targeting the div inside the anchor and Divs do not have text-decoration by default. You need to put the class on the anchor tag directly.